# How to use SQL AND condition in ElasticSearch query in PHP?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm learning ElasticSearch by following this - https://qbox.io/blog/using-elasticsearch-in-e-commerce-part-1 article. Index & type for elasticsearch has been created by running following CURL command.

```
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/ecomercedata/gadgets/_bulk?pretty' -d'
{ "index": { "_id": 1 }}
{ "name" : "MacBook Pro", "category" : "Laptop", "brand" : "Apple", "rating" : 9, "prize" :  1299.00, "piecesSold" : 9500,  "dateOfRelease" : "2005-02-01"}
{ "index": { "_id": 2 }}
{"name" : "MacBook Air",  "category" : "Laptop", "brand" : "Apple",  "rating" : 8,  "prize" :  1099.00,  "piecesSold" : 8700,   "dateOfRelease" : "2006-05-01"}
{ "index": { "_id": 3 }}
{"name" : "ATIV Book",  "category" : "Laptop",  "brand" : "Samsung",  "rating" : 8,  "prize" :  1899.00,  "piecesSold" : 3500,   "dateOfRelease" : "2014-05-01"}
{ "index": { "_id": 4 }}
{"name" : "Inspiron",  "category" : "Laptop",  "brand" : "Dell",  "rating" : 6,  "prize" :  700.00,  "piecesSold" : 4600,   "dateOfRelease" : "2008-03-01"}
{ "index": { "_id": 5 }}
{"name" : "Ipad",  "category" : "Tablet",  "brand" : "Apple",  "rating" : 9,  "prize" :  600.00,  "piecesSold" : 9500 ,  "dateOfRelease" : "2005-07-01"}
{ "index": { "_id": 6 }}
{"name" : "Galaxy Tab",  "category" : "Tablet",  "brand" : "Samsung",  "rating" : 8,  "prize" :  550.00,  "piecesSold" : 8500 ,  "dateOfRelease" : "2007-07-01"}
{ "index": { "_id": 7 }}
{"name" : "Lumia",  "category" : "Mobile",  "brand" : "Nokia",  "rating" : 6,  "prize" :  50.00,  "piecesSold" : 12000 ,  "dateOfRelease" : "2009-03-01"}
{ "index": { "_id": 8 }}
{"name" : "Iphone",  "category" : "Mobile", "brand" : "Apple",  "rating" : 8,  "prize" :  60.00,  "piecesSold" : 28000 ,  "dateOfRelease" : "2002-03-01"}
{ "index": { "_id": 9 }}
{"name" : "Xperia",  "category" : "Mobile",  "brand" : "Sony",  "rating" : 8,  "prize" :  70.00,  "piecesSold" : 24000 ,  "dateOfRelease" : "2004-03-01"}'
```

Field mapping Script used-

```
curl -X PUT "http://localhost:9200/ecomercedata/gadgets/_mapping" -d '{
  "gadgets" : {
    "properties" : {
      "category" : {
        "type" : "String",
    "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      "brand" : {
        "type" : "String",
    "index" : "not_analyzed"
      },
      "name" : {
        "type" : "String"
      },
      "rating" : {
        "type" : "Integer"
      },
      "dateOfRelease" : {
        "type" : "date",
        "format" : "YYYY-mm-dd"
      },
      "prize" :  {
        "type" : "Double"
      },
      "piecesSold" : {
        "type" : "Integer"
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

I'm using PHPto fetch records from ElasticSearch. Here is my PHP Script to do that.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$hosts = [
    'http://localhost:9200',        // SSL to localhost
];

$client = Elasticsearch\ClientBuilder::create()     // Instantiate a new ClientBuilder
                    ->setHosts($hosts)              // Set the hosts
                    ->build();

$params = [
            'index' => 'ecomercedata',
            'type' => 'gadgets',
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                        'constant_score' => [
                            'filter' => [
                                'bool' => [
                                    'must' => [
                                        'term' => [
                                            'category' => 'Laptop'
                                        ],
                                        'term' => [
                                            'brand' => 'Apple'
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                ]

            ]
        ];

try {
    $results = $client->search($params);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    exit;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($results);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

Basically, I'm trying to extract all records where `category=laptop and brand=Apple`. But, it's not giving me a right number of records. According to entered dataset, I should get 2 records but I'm getting 4 records. Seems like, that `category and brand` condition works like as `OR` rather than `AND`.

I googled a lot. But, can't able to figure out what's I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap each `term` query in its own associative array, otherwise one gets overridden by the other. Try this query instead.

```
$params = [
        'index' => 'ecomercedata',
        'type' => 'gadgets',
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                    'constant_score' => [
                        'filter' => [
                            'bool' => [
                                'must' => [
                                   [
                                    'term' => [
                                        'category' => 'Laptop'
                                    ]
                                   ],
                                   [
                                    'term' => [
                                        'brand' => 'Apple'
                                    ]
                                   ]
                                ]
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
            ]

        ]
    ];
```

Comment: Yeah, this one is working. Got my mistake. Thanks for this help.

Answer (score 2):

`bool` should ALWAYS be wrapped in `query` wherever it is placed.
Also, your `term` queries there is incorrect. They should be in their own arrays like so:

```
[
    'constant_score' => [
        'filter' => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must' => [
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                'category' => 'Laptop'
                            ]
                        ],
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                'brand' => 'Apple'
                            ]
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Comment: Do u mean ```bool``` should be inside ```query``` ?

Comment: `constant_score/filter` is the old way but it is still correct. The problem is different, see the other answer ;-)

Comment: Yeah, according to this doc - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_finding_multiple_exact_values.html it's fine.